# Qt Creator. Есть ли возможность многострочного редактирования текста (multi line text edit)?

Tags: qtcreator

Есть ли в Qt Creator возможность многострочного выбора/выделения (Multiple Selections) такого как реализовано в текстовом редакторе Sublime Text (http://www.sublimetext.com/) по хоткею Ctrl+D (Use Multiple Selections to rename variables quickly.
Here Ctrl+D is used to select the next occurrence of the current word.). Или что-то похожее?

Есть еще multi column edit. В Linux зажимаем Shift+Alt и стрелками вверх или вниз добавляем на новых строках курсоры, также при тех же зажатых клавишах и левой кнопки мышки, можно произвести вертикальное выделение...

P.S. как вариант еще нашел возможность "привязать" Sublime Text как сторонний инструмент. Tools - Options - Environment - External Tools -> в подменю Text добавил "Edit with SublimeText3"
[image: Добавление вызова Sublime Text в Qt Creator]

Привязал к хоткею. И теперь код (весь файл) по хоткей открывается в Sublime Text для нужной быстрой правки. Далее Ctrl+S (Сохранить), Alt+F4(Закрыть Sublime) и Enter для подтверждения изменений уже в самом Qt Creator.
Выглядит громоздко, но это всего пара хоткеев.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для массового переименования используйте комбанацию Ctrl-Shift-R или пункт контекстного меню Рефакторинг->Переименовать символ под курсором (В версии 3.2.2)

Comment: да Ctrl+Shift+R тоже годится для начала. Хоть это и немного не то что хотелось. В Sublime по Ctrl+D последовательно можно было выбирать в скольких местах изменить фрагмент или что-то отредактировать. Видимо для Qt Creator пока такого нет.

Comment: к сожалению эта комбинация работает только с именами которые выделяются Qt Creator по всему файлу. Если выделить часть любого слова, то повторения выделленого не происходит, а соответственно и редактировать в нескольких местах нет возможности. Например, не работает с типами, строками ... Работает с именами переменных, функций ...